# Keras flow_from_directory limiting number of examples

Tags: keras, generator

What's the simplest way I can use `flow_from_directory` in Keras while limiting the number of examples used in each subdirectory by some number `N`?

For context, I'd like to be able to use a small subset of the total images for testing purposes without having to create a separate top level directory for the smaller dataset, since I'm pulling this data from AWS S3 buckets during training.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### New Answer Edit

As pointed out in the comments, one should use [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) or pure Keras equivalent as `ImageDataGenerator` is deprecated.

### Old answer

Create `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` with argument `validation_split` specified as float. In such case you can use argument `subset` in `flow_from_directory` to get only some samples from each directory. More info [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory).

If you want `N` images from each folder specifically, you would have to calculate how many files are there in each directory, and set train-validation split accordingly.

Comment: I know the answer is old, but ImageDataGenerator is deprecated. New code should not be created using this method. Now we should use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`